How to find coordinates of selected objects OpenCV?
In general, I highlighted these objects in red using OpenCV, but I don’t know how to find their coordinates:

Initially it all looked like this:

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


img = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()


You have several contours. The result contours contains several. You could calculate the center for each contour.

You already have the coordinates of each point for each contour. If you want to calculate instead the center of each contour, would be something like that, using moments:
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    if M["m00"] != 0:
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    else:
        cX, cY = 0, 0

